# Too many open files when I run a infinite socket open and close

Tags: c, sockets

I have searched all about this question at this website.

my program scenario is:

- there is one server that always listens for a request from  a client.
- there is one client that always requests a `char` from the server in 2 second periods

get the error message:

> Too many open files" happened on socket() function after the program run about 1024 times.

My current solution is to increase the number of open files: 
`"ulimit -n 5000"`, but I don't think this is a perfect solution, because it will make the program run 5000 times.

So, does anybody have a better solution?

Environment:

- ubuntu 10
- c language

My code as following:

Client:

```
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
int socket_port = 9734;

while (1) {

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        DieWithSystemMessage("socket() failed");//<<===========Too many open files
    memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    address.sin_port = socket_port;
    //Establish the connection to the server
    if ((connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address)))
            < 0)
        DieWithSystemMessage("connect() failed");

    if (rename_count % 2 == 0)
        ch = 'A';
    else if (rename_count % 2 == 1)
        ch = 'B';
    else
        ch = 'E';
    ssize_t numBytes = send(sockfd, &ch, strlen(&ch), 0);

    if (numBytes < 0)
        DieWithSystemMessage("send() failed");
    else if (numBytes != strlen(&ch))
        DieWithUserMessage("send()", "sent unexpected number of bytes");
    //fflush(sockfd);
    shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_RDWR);

    rename_count++;

}
```

Server:

```
int server_sockfd, client_sockfd;
int server_len, client_len;
socklen_t clntAddrLen;
struct sockaddr_in server_address;
struct sockaddr_in client_address;
uint64_t start_time_micro, end_time_micro;
int socket_num = 9734;

server_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (server_sockfd < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("socket() failed");

memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
server_address.sin_port = socket_num;

if ((bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address,
        sizeof(server_address))) < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("bind() failed");
if ((listen(server_sockfd, 5)) < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("listen() failed");


while (1) {
    char ch;
    printf("\nserver waiting\n");

    //accept a connect
    clntAddrLen = sizeof(client_address);
    client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd,
            (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, &clntAddrLen);
    if (client_sockfd < 0)
        DieWithSystemMessage("accept() failed");
    //reading and writing through client side
    ssize_t numBytesRcvd = recv(client_sockfd, &ch, 1, 0);
    if (numBytesRcvd < 0)
        DieWithSystemMessage("recv() failed");

    if (ch == 'A') {
        rename_num = 0;//printf("A\n");
    } else if (ch == 'B') {
        rename_num = 1;//printf("B\n");
    } else
        ;

    printf("%d. Got it!!!\n", i);

    close(client_sockfd);
}
close(server_sockfd);
```

Comment: You probably want to replace `strlen(&ch)` with `1` (2 occurences in the client code).

Comment: yeah, my problem is clear. my summary is that: Too many open files error is made by you open a lot of file descriptor and don't free the file descriptor correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You're shutting down the socket in the client but never closing it. It's not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

There is a big difference between `shutdown()` and `close()`.  When you "shutdown" a socket, you're putting it into a "half-closed" condition where it is still possible to send or receive (depending on which half you shut down) over the connection.

The socket is still valid, TCP still maintains state information about the connection, and the port is still "open", and the socket/file-descriptor is still allocated to your process.

When you call `close()` the socket/file-descriptor is free'd **but the rest remains**.  TCP must hold resources for some amount of time, typically 2 minutes (it depends on who did the close and some other things) during which the state information and the local port itself are still "in use".

So even though you may no longer exceed the file-descriptor limit for your process, it is theoretically possible to saturate the resources of the networking stack and *still* not be able to open a new connection.